# Jquery : How to move TD to another TR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've generated html and I need to restructuring the html using Jquery, like this:

Original:

```
<table id="myTableID">
<tr id="tr01">
    <td>Col 1 Value</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr02">
    <td>Col 2 Value</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr03">
    <td>Col 3 Value</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr04">
    <td>Col 4 Value</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Expected:

```
<table id="myTableID">
<tr id="tr01">
    <td>Col 1 Value</td>
    <td>Col 2 Value</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr02">
    <td>Col 3 Value</td>
    <td>Col 4 Value</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr03">
</tr>
<tr id="tr04">
</tr>
</table>

var tableNew = "<table id='myTableID'>"+
       "<tr><td>new "+
       "</td></tr>"+
       "</table>";

       $('#myTableID').replaceWith(tableNew);
```

I came up with idea with iterate and replace, any better idea?

Comment: do you have fixed number of trs

Comment: @ArunPJohny: no, it was generated by server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one-line jQuery will do what you need. Just apply it to each row you need to reformat:

```
$('#tr01').append($('#tr02').contents());
```

There's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9kxD/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$( "#tr03 > td" ).appendTo( "#tr01" );
```

You can refer : http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: Did you mean `$( "#tr03 > td" ).appendTo( $("#tr01") );`

Answer (score 0):

My one cent - use [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the td's and then move the tds around so that you preserve the events attached to them, if any.

Comment: If the elements were moved with `.append()` or `.appendTo()` the event handlers would be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $rows = $('#myTableID tr');

$rows.slice(0, Math.ceil($rows.length / 2)).each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index();
    $this.append($rows.eq(index * 2).find('td'))
    $this.append($rows.eq(index * 2 + 1).find('td'))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a22Bq/)

Answer (score 0):

this is other option you can create/replace table by click of button

```
max = 2

$("button").click(function() {
    var tr = $("table tr:last");
    if(!tr.length || tr.find("td").length >= max)
        $("table").append("<tr>");
    $("table tr:last").append("<td>hi</td>");
});

<table border=1></table>
<button>hi</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var all_td = $('#myTableID tr').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
$('#myTableID tr').empty().each(function(i){
    var ret  = all_td.slice(i*2,++i*2);
    $(this).html(ret);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/CN5p6/)</kbd>

---

Each `tr` will have two `td`