# jquery - how to move td to another td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a table like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><select id="B" name="B">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td class="sample">F: will hide/show</td>
        <td class="sample">G: will hide/show</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I</td>
        <td class="id1">J</td>
        <td class="id1">K</td>
        <td>L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>M</td>
        <td class="id2">N</td>
        <td class="id2">O</td>
        <td>P</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, whenever I change the value in `<td>B` select option , `<td>F` and `<td>G` will hide..
It will then move up belows `<td>`... 
`<td>J` & `<td>K`  to  `<td>F` & `<td>G` , 
`<td>N` & `<td>O`  to  `<td>J` & `<td>K` ,

Opposite happens if `<td>F` and `<td>G` will be shown.. other `<td>` will move down

here is the jquery ive started.

```
$('select#B').change(function(event) {

          if (this.value == '2') {
                $(".sample").show();
          } else {
                $(".sample").hide();
          }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rucsh/40/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780459/jquery-how-to-move-td-to-another-tr check with this one

Comment: append/prepend would help you.

Comment: These 2 may also help u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535139/move-td-element-and-reorder-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865324/how-to-block-movement-of-tr-in-jquery-sortable

Comment: i don't get it. when you change the drop down you want to hide/show data. when value 1: show/hide "x" and then when value 2:.... its hard for me to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Seabizkit when I change the value of select option either 1 / 3..  F and G should be hidden.. moving up their corresponding tds below

Comment: can't understand completely your question.... but check this update to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rucsh/41/ and let me know if *the result* is what you expect (the way is not the best one btw)

Comment: @JordiCastilla , thanks,, but how can I move J&K and N&O  up, since there's a blank space in between

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer is what you want, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('select#B').change(function(event) {

var clone = $('td.id1').clone();
var clone2 = $('td.id2').clone();

          if (this.value == '2') {
                $(".sample, td.id1, td.id2").show();
                $('.clone').remove();
          } else {
                $(".sample, td.id1, td.id2").hide();
                $(clone).insertAfter('.sample:last').addClass('clone');
                $(clone2).insertAfter('.id1:last').addClass('clone');
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><select id="B" name="B">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td class="sample">F: will hide/show</td>
        <td class="sample">G: will hide/show</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I</td>
        <td class="id1">J</td>
        <td class="id1">K</td>
        <td>L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>M</td>
        <td class="id2">N</td>
        <td class="id2">O</td>
        <td>P</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

High-level instructions,

1. Clone the target element you want to move
2. Save it variable
3. Remove the original element
4. Insert the cloned element (in step 2) to the desired location.

All above steps can be easily competed using jQuery.

Comment: No problem, happy hacking! :D Next time when you have similar issue, try to solve the issue at a higher level.